# Got 502 Bad Gateway with Golang's Http.Hijacker

Tags: go

I've read [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334265/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-http-hijacker) and the example from [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27075478/when-to-use-hijack-in-golang)

Here's my demo:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler1)
    _ = http.ListenAndServe(":8008", nil)
}

func handler1(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    hijacker, _ := writer.(http.Hijacker)
    conn, buf, _ := hijacker.Hijack()
    defer conn.Close()
    _, _ = buf.WriteString("hello world")
    _ = buf.Flush()
}
```

I ran the code with `go run serv1.go` and sent request with `curl`, but got `HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway`. Just wondering if the API has been changed or anything I'd missed?

```
❯ curl -i "http://localhost:8008/"
HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=4
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: Using the server and command in the question, curl reports a different and expected error (Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed).  The program does not write an HTTP/1.1 502 as shown in the question.